# Pytorch でエラー TypeError: linear(): argument 'input' (position 1) must be Tensor, not int

Tags: python, pytorch

このコードだとエラーが出てしまいます。どう改善すればいいですか？

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
TypeError: linear(): argument 'input' (position 1) must be Tensor, not int
```

**ソースコード:**

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
model = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(10, 32),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(32, 16),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(16, 10)
)
device = torch.device('cpu')
sample = torch.ones([4], dtype=torch.float64, device=device)
y=model(input=10)
x=y(sample)
```

Comment: この記事 [PyTorchでモデル（ネットワーク）を構築・生成](https://note.nkmk.me/python-pytorch-module-sequential/) の説明の「生成したモデルは呼び出し可能（`xxx()`で実行可能）で、適切なサイズの`torch.Tensor`を引数として与えると結果が得られる。」あたりが該当するのでは？

Comment: それでやってみたら動きました！
tensor([[-0.1131, -0.2007,  0.4459, -0.0388,  0.3776, -0.4242, -0.1299,  0.1176,
          0.1349, -0.0125],
        [-0.2050, -0.1167,  0.2475, -0.0103, -0.0287, -0.1848,  0.1535,  0.0317,
         -0.1443, -0.0373],
        [-0.0827, -0.1034,  0.0863,  0.0220, -0.1633,  0.0679, -0.2714,  0.0891,
          0.2191,  0.0834]], grad_fn=<AddmmBackward0>)

Comment: それは良かったですね。実際の解決内容を自己回答にしておくと情報共有になりますのでよろしくお願いします。